# Generalizing the concept of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An ODE is a relationship such as $F(t,y(t),\dots,y^{(n)}(t))=0$ with $F:\Omega \subset R \times R^n \to R^n$, $\Omega$ open set not empty.
What happens if $F$ is similar, but  contains derivative of $y$ arbitrary large?
Does anyone know where I can find some material that talks about this theme?

For example, the easiest thing that bumps in my mind:
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} y^{(i)}=0$
Now, lets put initial conditions : $y^{(n)}(0)=n^2$ for all $n\in N$

What can I say about the solutions of this equation?
I don't expect to calculate them analitically, but can I get some info? (Existence, unicity, global existence...)

Comment: Well, at the very least, the solutions to $\sum_0^n y^{(i)}(x) = 0\;\;;\;\;y^{(i)}(0) = i^2$ seem to converge as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which suggests there is a solution of sorts.

Comment: If you introduce a new function for each derivative this becomes an infinite system of first order ODE, which might be easier to deal with, especially if linear

Comment: You encounter such equations in physics quite a lot. However, they usually have the form $f(D)y(x)=\lambda{y(x)}$, where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $f$ is $C^{\infty}$. E.g. Bloch functions in 1D satisfy $e^{aD}y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n!}y^{(n)}=cy(x)$.

Comment: @KirylPesotski, a great example! The same with time propagation in quantum mechanics. I didn't think of this